# Is it possible to install the Haskell Platform on CentOS?

Tags: haskell, centos

I'm running CentOS 5.5 and I want to install the Haskell Platform there. According to haskell.org CentOS is not supported at all (http://hackage.haskell.org/platform/linux.html). Does anyone know if it is possible to setup Haskell on CentOS 5.5? I searched the web but could not find any relevant information myself.

Comment: googled - built for 5.2 http://haskell.1045720.n5.nabble.com/building-Haskell-Platform-for-CentOS-5-2-with-a-tmp-mounted-noexec-td3146361.html and http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2010-April/076489.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try compiling from source.  This is the recommended way to install the Haskell platform when there is no binary package for your OS.  [This guy](http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2010-April/076489.html) was able to build it for CentOS 5.2.

- [Haskell Platform from source on Unix-like](http://www.vex.net/~trebla/haskell/haskell-platform.xhtml)

Comment: The recommended way?  By who?  I've not had an issue using the [generic Linux binaries](http://haskell.org/ghc/download_ghc_7_0_2#x86linux) available on the ghc site.

Comment: "Why you may like to build Haskell Platform from source: there is no binary package for your OS;" (from the link in my answer)

Comment: I guess I am the one "recommending" it haha. I am a Ubuntu user, but I still build Haskell, Ruby, and Clojure from source instead of using the binary packages.  If you are getting along fine with the generic Linux binaries, no reason to switch.

Comment: I'll give it a go on CentOS 5.5. Thanks.